# Why am I getting this access violation?

Tags: c++, access-violation, char-pointer

I'm probably doing something stupid here, but it's been a while since I've worked in C++ and for some reason I keep getting an access violation when sprintf is called. Anyways, here's the code I'm using:

```
char *value, *result;
int len;
result = "";
mgr.GetObjValue(0, value, len);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
{
  sprintf(result, "%s %X", result, value[i]);
}

printf("ObjVal: %s\n\n", result);
```

if anyone is curious what GetObjValue does, it just retrieves the SNMP object value from the API I am using. Here's it's declaration:

```
int SNMPMgr::GetObjValue(int iObjIndex, char *&lpObjValue, int &lenObjValue);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: In fact no space is reserved at all, `result` points to static memory …

Comment: @chris - actually not even one character - result is just a dangling pointer.

Comment: @filmor, You're right. I'm not thinking straight. Overwriting even that one character is bad.

Comment: @chris - which one character?

Comment: Th pointer is pointing to a string literal, It cannot be modified, its Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @chris - ah! I didn't see the `result = ""` - Anyway, that's a literal as Als says - it leads to undefined behaviour to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprintf` doesn't do memory allocation.  It expects to be given a pointer to a writable buffer of sufficient length to hold the data.

```
char *result;
```

At this point, result's contents are undefined.

```
result = "";
```

At this point, result points to a static, read-only string of 1 byte (the terminating null).

```
sprintf(result, "%s %X", result, value[i]);
```

At this point, you just tried to write an arbitrarily long string to a read-only area of size 1.  Oops.

Do something like this instead:

```
char result[1024];
sprintf(result, "%s %X", result, value[i]);
```

Note that using [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) or [sprintf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx), to avoid even the possibility of overwriting your buffer, is probably a good idea.  (Since you're using C++, you could also easily use one of the C++ formatting libraries, like [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/libs/format/), that does memory allocation for you - but that's a whole other topic.)

Comment: Even then, in the for loop, each iteration would overwrite the last iteration

Comment: Thanks, as I said, I was sure I was doing something dumb and sure enough, not allocating memory is pretty bad. Thanks, for the detailed response though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `char* result = "";`

You're attempting to print to a constant string (the empty string). From the documentation for sprintf regarding the first parameter:

> Pointer to a buffer where the resulting C-string is stored. The buffer
>   should be large enough to contain the resulting string.

You need to allocate a buffer to print to.